# What was the plan for season two of Limitless?

Tags: limitless-tv

I was just wondering, how was the senator Morra plot meant to unfold?

Answer (score 3):

**There are not a lot of specifics, but...**

### **From Executive Producer Craig Sweeney:**

> [Sweeney](https://www.celebeat.com/articles/26771/20170626/limitless-season-2-producer-hints-new-plot-for-the-series-series-to-air-on-netflix-or-amazon.htm) **previously revealed that he has big plans for "Limitless"
> season 2 but it may not focus on Brian Finch (Jake McDorman) any
> longer after his big secret was revealed unless there will be drastic
> changes. "I think that unless something were to change fairly
> drastically, there would be no place for him there," he told IGN. "His
> utility to them is as somebody who can take NZT without the harmful
> side effects... so Brian's time at the FBI is over**."

#### AND Speculation from ScreenRant:

> [Limitless](https://screenrant.com/limitless-season-2-updates-story-release/) essentially took its literally mind-altering concept
> and turned it into a procedural, which arguably wasn't the most
> creative direction to go in. **Limitless season 2 would have seen the
> public aware of the NZT drug and Morra going missing, which would have
> changed the whole dynamic.**
>
> **That said, the crux of Limitless season 2 apparently would have still
> involved Finch solving crimes, so it wouldn't have been a major
> shakeup. Morra had also announced his candidacy for President, which
> no doubt would have been a major subplot.** Unfortunately, with Netflix
> and other platforms having long since passed on it, season 2 looks
> very doubtful.